# How to save dask array as .png files slice by slice?

Tags: dask

I'm running a machine learning pipeline for segmentation of very large 3D images. I would like to store the results (dask arrays) as .png files, with each file corresponding to one slice of the dask array. Do you have any suggestions on how to implement this?

I have been trying to save the results by building a parallel for loop using the joblib dask parallel backend and then looping through the results slice by slice. This works fine until a certain point at which my pipe gets stuck without any apparent reason (no memory issue, no too many open file descriptors etc.).

array_to_save has been persisted in memory with client.persist()

```
with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    joblib.Parallel(verbose=100)(joblib.delayed(png_sav)(j, stack_height, client.compute(array_to_save[j])) for j in range(stack_height))

def png_sav(j, stack_height, prediction):

    img = Image.fromarray(prediction.result().astype('uint32'), 'I') # I to save as 16 bit binary image
    img.save(png_pn+str(j)+'_slice_prediction.png', "PNG")
    img.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using either ...

1. the `map_blocks` method to call a function on every block of your data.  Your function can take a `block_info=` keyword argument if it wants to know where it is in the stack.
2. Convert your array to a list of delayed arrays.  Maybe something like this (untested, you should read the docs here)

   ```
   x = x.rechunk((1, None, None))  # many chunks along the first axis
   slices = x.to_delayed().flatten()
   saves = [dask.delayed(numpy_array_to_png)(slc, filename='...') for slc in slices]
   dask.compute(*saves)
   ```
3. Check in with the dask-image project.  I suspect that they have something https://github.com/dask/dask-image

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your hints.
I'm trying to understand how to use .map_blocks() and in particular block_info=. But I don't understand how to use the information given by block_info. I would like to save each chunk separately but don't know how to do this. Any hints? Thanks a lot!

```
da.map_blocks(png_sav(stack_height, prediction, 
                  block_info=True), dtype='uint16')

def png_sav(stack_height, prediction, block_info=True):

    # I don't get how I can save each chunk separately
    img = Image.fromarray("prediction_chunk".astype('uint32'), 'I') # I to save as 16 bit binary image
    img.save(png_pn+str(j)+'_slice_prediction.png', "PNG")
    img.close()
```